# Implementing rights with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

We are currently working on a smaller ASP.NET MVC 5 application using ASP.NET Identity. It allows us to maintain different projects and their tasks. We recently implemented basic authentication so we are able to register a user with our site and login with them.

We want to be able to manage access rights on project basis so we can say for every single user that he has read, write, admin or no permissions for a specified project.

My first thought was that we can create a simple new table in our database which stores the user rights. But I feel that there might be a built-in way to achieve this with ASP.NET Identity.

So my question really is, which path we should follow - manually building a new table to administer the rights or use something built-in provided by ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Maybe this article will help you make a decision: http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Ther is no built in concept of user rights in asp.net identity as they are a very application specific concept. There is a concept of user roles, which is just a logical grouping of users. You usually apply a set of specific user writes to a role.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would suggest to create a role for every access restriction (read/write/admin) for every project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> use something built-in provided by ASP.NET Identity

The only things you could use there are claims or roles and both are not built for what you want IMO.

So I would go with your own table which links the project to a user, e.g.:

```
public class UserProjectRights
{
    [Key]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public AccessRight Right { get; set; }
}
```

Then whenever you do some actions where a specific right is required you need to check for that. There are several ways how you could do that. In my app I created "access right check extensions" like the following (I have defined a common interface for all "access right entities" to "reuse" that method):

```
public static bool? CanView(this ApplicationUser user, Project project)
{
     var userRight = project.Rights.FirstOrDefault(r => r.User == user);
     return userRight == null ? (bool?)null : userRight.Right.HasFlag(AccessRight.View);
}
```

assuming `AccessRight` is an enum like:

```
[Flags]
public enum AccessRight
{
    View,
    Edit,
    Admin
}
```

Then you can do something like the following in your logic:

```
if (user.CanView(project) == true)
{
    // show project
}
```

I used `bool?` so I can implement different "default behaviour" as I know if `null` is returned there is no right defined.

Comment: And then in every controller that does something with some project or project-related entity you need to check whether the user has the appropriate right on the given (parent) project.

Comment: `The only things you could use there are claims or roles and both are not built for what you want IMO` - I've quite happily used claims before to provide "role on project" behaviour like OP describes.

Comment: @ChrFin the latter. You're not quite there by just creating a table. Not that it's _required_ in your answer, but OP and future visitors might be confused.

Comment: @Rawling: But when you have a lot of projects you get a lot of claims and huge cookies, which is not recommended...

Comment: @Rawling: As ChrFin stated there might be the problem of having a lot of claims. It would be helpful if you could clarify your way of achieving the behavior required.

Comment: I merely wanted to point out that you don't have to dismiss the built-in claims out-of-hand. I can't remember the exact implementation but IIRC we simply had a custom claim type with a `project:role` string as the value, and gave the users as many instances of that claim type as they needed. We never ran into cookie size problems but after a five-minute Google I found out that it is possible to [cache the claims on the server side and only send a reference in the cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytoken.isreferencemode.aspx).

Comment: @Rawling: Maybe you can post an answer showing such an implementation? I am also interested in such a solution as it may can be usefull for me too in some other cases...

Comment: @CodeCaster: I now updated my answer with a simple usage example. Do you think this is sufficient to aid people getting into such a system or should I elaborate more?

Comment: @ChrFin Again, I can't remember my exact implementation, hence the fact I am merely commenting to say it's not impossible rather than providing my own answer.